# lme4 mixed model error

Tags: r, mixed, anova

What is wrong with the following model:

```
 # simulated data yr = 2; vg = 4, fm = 5, gen = 5
    mbb <- data.frame( trait1 = rnorm(200, 15, 4),yr = c(rep (1:2, each = 100)), 
   vg = c(rep(rep(1:4, each =25), 2)), fm = rep(rep(1:5, each = 5), 8), 
    gen = sample(c(1:5), 200, replace = T))
    require(lme4) 
    lmer(trait1 ~ (yr + vg + gen)^3 + (yr + vg + gen|fm:vg), data= mbb)# full model
```

I am getting following error:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class "mer" object: Slot Zt must by dims['q']  by dims['n']*dims['s']
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In fm:vg : numerical expression has 200 elements: only the first used
2: In fm:vg : numerical expression has 200 elements: only the first used
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the interaction bit of your random effect.  Change `gen|fm:vg` to `gen|fm` and it runs.  Not yet sure of the meaning of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is precisely that `fm` and `vg` are stored as numeric, not as factors, and so `lmer` tries to interpret `fm:vg` as a sequence operator (see `?seq`) rather than an interaction operator (see `?interaction`).  You can:

- convert `fm` and `vg` to factors within the data frame (`mbb <- transform(mbb,vg=factor(vg),fm=factor(fm))`) [*it's not clear from your setup whether you want `vg` and `fm` to be factors or continuous predictors ... that distinction would be very important, of course ... if you want them as continuous predictors, then it's a bit weird to treat them as factors for the purposes of grouping ...* ]
- write the interaction explicitly as `interaction(fm,vg)` on the fly
- convert to factors on the fly (`(yr+vg+gen|factor(fm):factor(vg))`)
- use Jim M.'s solution

  I *think* these will all work, although I have to admit that I haven't tested them.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution to model the interaction as a random effect is to add the interaction term as an additional column in the mbb data frame.

```
mbb$fmvg <- with(mbb, interaction(fm,vg, sep=":"))
```

The model then becomes

```
lmer(trait1 ~ (yr + vg + gen)^3 + (yr + vg + gen|fmvg), data= mbb)
```